# Err. ENOENT when renaming a file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upload a file in my node/express app, but everytime I've got the ENOENT error when renaming the file. My code is that:

```
var tmp_path = req.files.file.path;
fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function (err) { 
    if(err) throw err;
    ...
    });
```

where target_path will be the destination path. If I do:

```
console.log('exists ' + fs.existsSync(tmp_path));
```

then my server logs:

```
exists true
```

Also, listing the contents of tmp directory shows that the file is there. What's the problem?

Comment: What is the target_path? Remember that fs will not create missing directories for you -- you'll need to explicitly create them if they are not found.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.

Comment: Cool. I'll add a formal answer if you like, since I remember this behavior surprised me the first time I encountered it, too.

Answer (score 1):

FS methods like `fs.rename` which create, move or rename files expect that any directories in the path *already exist*. When they do not, you'll get an ENOENT. Since very often what you mean is "make this file -- and any directories in the path I specify for it" you may want to consider using an NPM library that abstracts access to fs with methods that take care of such things.

There are quite a few options. For example [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) is one of the better-tested libraries. Using fs-extra you can use `ensureDir` in that operation to make the directory structure first if it does not yet exist.